# Set primary key with two integers

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a table with primary key (ColumnA, ColumnB). I want to make a function or procedure that when passed two integers will insert a row into the table but make sure the largest integer always goes into ColumnA and the smaller one into ColumnB.

So if we have SetKeysWithTheseNumbers(17, 19) would return

```
|-----------------|
|ColumnA | ColumnB|
|-----------------|
|19      | 17     |
|-----------------|
```

SetKeysWithTheseNumbers(19, 17) would return the same thing

```
|-----------------|
|ColumnA | ColumnB|
|-----------------|
|19      | 17     |
|-----------------|
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
INSERT INTO your_table
  (COLUMN_A, COLUMN_B)
VALUES(GREATEST(@param_a, @param_b), 
       LEAST(@param_a, @param_b))
```

Reference:

- [GREATEST](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest)
- [LEAST](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_least)

Comment: That's what I was looking for word for word. I couldn't figure out the equivalent to max and min.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a store procedure

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `SetKeysWithTheseNumbers` $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `SetKeysWithTheseNumbers` (

n1 integer,
n2 integer


)
BEGIN

declare n3 integer;
declare n4 integer;

if( n1 > n2 ) then
 set n3=n1;
 set n4=n2;
else
 set n3=n2;
 set n4=n1;
end if;

insert into mytable values(n3,n4);



END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: That seems to do the trick, thanks. I thought I will just use two insert statements though instead of the assignation of n3, n4.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [triggers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-trigger.html):

```
delimiter //

CREATE TRIGGER greater_ColA_table
  BEFORE INSERT ON table 
  FOR EACH ROW 
  BEGIN
    DECLARE a INTEGER;
    IF NEW.ColumnA < NEW.ColumnB THEN
      SET a=NEW.ColumnA; 
      SET NEW.ColumnA=NEW.ColumnB, NEW.ColumnB=a;
    END IF; 
  END //

delimiter ;
```

Repeat for the `BEFORE UPDATE` event.